# How can I get fast external ssd safely?

Tags: ssd, thunderbolt

I want to get Thunderbolt speeds for my M1 Mac Mini for a low price, but it's confusing.  If I buy a fast external drive, I may get slow speed because of low power.  If I buy a powered thunderbolt 3 hub, I can get faster speed, but all the powered hubs sold on Amazon have people complaining that their ports were fried by those hubs.  Is there a safe hub?  Is there a powered drive that doesn't cost the moon?  What's the solution?

Comment: could you clarify your question - are you looking for a drive that runs fast when plugged in directly, or a thunderbolt 3 hub that can deliver enough power to multiple accessories, including a drive, that is safe to use?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you asking for a product recommendation?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for recommendations or an explanation of how to think about this.  I want something fast at the lowest cost.  If I can plug a drive into the thunderbolt port and get 40 Gb/s, that would be great, but from what I'm reading, that sort of speed requires a hub.  And I'm guessing it requires a powered hub.  And a powered hub, moreover seems to be dangerous.  If it's badly made, it can destroy the computer and/or it's ports.   And it's not easy to find any sort of explanation from Apple or Apple users.

Answer (score 2):

There is no necessity for a Thunderbolt drive to require a hub between it and the computer.

There'a also some possible confusion between "Thunderbolt drives" and "USB-C drives", as both use the same port/connector. Most portable drives that do not require a separate power supply are likely to be USB-C, rather than TB.

True Thunderbolt drives are likely to be larger units, such as RAID systems, that have their own power supply.

There have been reports of cheap USB-C hub that have a power supply coming in causing [problems with M1 Macs](https://createdtech.com/are-usb-c-docks-killing-macbooks/). But this relates to charging Macs with batteries, and so does not affect a Mini.

There have also been problems reported with the connection speed of external drives on M1 Macs.
https://eclecticlight.co/2022/04/18/m1-thunderbolt-ports-dont-fully-support-usb-3-1-gen-2/

This may not be enough information to remove all confusion. I would also ask what you plan to use the drive for, and whether high speeds are essential.

Comment: This. The last question ("What you plan to use the drive for") is the essential query to avoid an X-Y problem.